# Navier-Stokes - Complete set under turbulent eddy viscosity hypothesis

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

I'm looking for the complete set (x,y,z component) of the Navier-Stoke equations under the Eddy Viscosity hypothesis to model turbulent fluid flow.

I found the [following](http://www.calpoly.edu/~kshollen/ME554/RANS.pdf), but I have a really hard time believing the transition from the next to last set of equations to the last set of equations. I used the [eddy viscosity hypothesis](http://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Boussinesq_eddy_viscosity_assumption) but I could not get terms to cancel to give the last set of equations. Using the eddy viscosity hypothesis:
\begin{equation}
- \overline{u'_i u'_j} = \nu_t \, \left( \frac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial \overline{u_j}}{\partial x_i}  \right) - \frac{2}{3} k \delta_{ij} = \nu_t \, \left( \frac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial \overline{u_j}}{\partial x_i}  \right) -\frac{1}{3} \left( \overline{u'^2} + \overline{v'^2}  \right)\delta_{ij}
\end{equation}

$\overline{u'^2} = -2\nu_T \frac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial x}$, $\overline{v'^2} = -2\nu_T \frac{\partial \bar{v}}{\partial y}$ and  $\overline{u'v'} = -\nu_T ( \frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial \bar{v}}{\partial x} ) = \overline{v'u'}$

For example, in two-dimensional flow, for the x-momentum equation

\begin{equation}
-\frac{\partial \overline{u'^2}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \nu_T}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial x} + \nu_T \frac{\partial^2 \bar{u}}{\partial x^2} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
-\frac{\partial \overline{u'v'} }{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \nu_T}{\partial y} ( \frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial \bar{v}}{\partial x} ) + \nu_T ( \frac{\partial^2 \bar{u}}{\partial y^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 \bar{v}}{\partial y \partial x} ) 
\end{equation}

I can't see how the sum of these two terms simplifies to give the first equation in the last set of equations on page 2 where the viscosities are added in each term.

Answer (score 3):

The reference that you show, makes it overly complicated to see the steps that are taken. In fluid dynamics, it is worth to familiarize yourself with [index notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation). You can reduced the three sets of equations for $u$, $v$ and $w$ to a single equation for $u_i$, where $i\in{1,2,3}$. Furthermore, you sum over the repeated index (often $j$).

In non-conservative form (and divided by $\rho$, the Navier-Stokes equations can then simply be written as
$$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t}+u_j\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \nu \frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2}$$

The continuity equation in index notation would reduce to
$$\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j}=0$$

Applying Reynolds averaging on the linear terms is straightforward, as the mean of the fluctuating part is always zero. Therefore, I will now only address the non-linear term.

Working out the nonlinear term using Reynolds decomposition gives

$$ u_j\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} = (\overline{u_j}+u'_j)\frac{\partial (\overline{u_i}+u'_i)}{\partial x_j}$$

which expands to four terms
$$u_j\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} =
\overline{u_j}\frac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j}+
u'_j\frac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j}+
\overline{u_j}\frac{\partial u'_i}{\partial x_j}+
u'_j\frac{\partial u'_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Reynolds averaging this equation, does not have an effect ong the first term.

The second term vanishes, because $\overline{u'_j}=0$ and the third because $\overline{u'_i}=0$.

The fourth term can be written in conservative form as well to give $\displaystyle\frac{\partial \overline{u'_i u'_j}}{\partial x_j}$, because $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u'_j}{\partial x_j}=0$ (from continuity). On this last term you apply the Boussinesq or eddy viscosity hypothesis.

Comment: I understand how he gets to the conclusion of the equations on the middle of the second page. What I don't understand is how he is able to simplify them using the Boussinesq or eddy viscosity hypothesis to the last set of equations on page 2. I have updated my original post.

Comment: The Boussinesq hypothesis is no more than substituting $\nu_\tau\frac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j}$ for $\overline{u'_i u'_j}$

Comment: Your equations are incompressible, which simplifies it a bit.

Comment: only the term $\frac{\partial U_k}{\partial x_k}$ vanishes due to incompressibility?

Comment: is it not:$-\rho \overline{u'_i u'_j} = \mu_t \, \left( \frac{\partial U_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial U_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{2}{3} \frac{\partial U_k}{\partial x_k} \delta_{ij} \right) - \frac{2}{3} \rho k \delta_{ij}$ which simplifies to $- \overline{u'_i u'_j} = \nu_t \, \left( \frac{\partial U_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial U_j}{\partial x_i}  \right) - \frac{2}{3} k \delta_{ij} = \nu_t \, \left( \frac{\partial U_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial U_j}{\partial x_i}  \right) -\frac{1}{3} \left( \overline{u'^2} + \overline{v'^2}  \right)\delta_{ij} $

Comment: I don't know it this far by hard, but check which terms vanish by taking the divergence.